# Uncaught ReferenceError: testString is not defined

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

This is really weird..

I need to send a couple of variables through to jquery from PHP.. one is an INT and the other a string.

When $a is an INT it works fine but when i use a string, i get this error.. `Uncaught ReferenceError: testString is not defined`

Here is my code.

```
<?php $a = 'testString'; ?>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var a = <?php echo $a; ?>;
    alert(a);
</script>
```

I assumed that i needed to stick a (int) or (string) before the variable, but i wasn't entirely sure how to and unsuccessful in my googles/attempts.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You forgot the quotes to make the value of `var a` a string:

```
var a = "<?php echo $a; ?>";
```

What you're writing into the document is:

```
var a = testString;
```

so javascript is looking for a variable called `testString`. Instead, you want the result to be:

```
var a = "testString";
```

so make sure you include the quotes around what php is writing in.

Comment: Oh wow.. this has literally been an hour of hair pulling.. Works now! I'll get you that big green tick when the system allows

Comment: @user2950370 heh, no problem. I've been there.

Answer (score 3):

There are quotes missing in javascript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var a = '<?php echo $a; ?>';
  alert(a);
</script>
```